# Mutate to create two number columns from one number column based on a character value

Tags: r, dplyr

My data "x" looks like this:

```
date   type  cost
20-01  supp  5
20-02  supp  10
20-03  supp  5
20-01  svcs  2
20-02  svcs  4
20-03  svcs  8
```

I want to create a cost for each type in order to plot a multiple time series, which I can do by creating two separate time series, but what I'd like to do is create:

```
bydate <- aggregate(cbind(supp, svcs)~date, data=y, FUN=sum)
```

With my data "y" looking like this:

```
date   type  supp  svcs
20-01  supp  5     0
20-02  supp  10    0
20-03  supp  5     0
20-01  svcs  0     2
20-02  svcs  0     4
20-03  svcs  0     8
```

In this way I hope to create

```
df <- bydate %>% 
  select(date, supp, svcs) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -date)
```

Is the mutate function the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to create index variables before `pivot`ing, and then pivot_wider with the `valueS_fill` argument set to `0`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
        mutate(index = row_number(),
               type2 = type) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = type2, values_from = cost, values_fill = 0) %>%
        select(-index)
  

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  date  type   supp  svcs
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 20-01 supp      5     0
2 20-02 supp     10     0
3 20-03 supp      5     0
4 20-01 svcs      0     2
5 20-02 svcs      0     4
6 20-03 svcs      0     8
```

Comment: apologies, larger data set may be the problem, but with this data I'm still getting an error - ```Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.```

Comment: did you load the libraries? I can not reproduce your error, this looks fine to me. I can see you are piping the data from preliminary steps. Your problem likely lies in these steps, as I am getting consistent resultos with the example data provided

Comment: We can only help so much without a PROPER reproducible example, @Doug. Please share data and code as to reproduce the issues you are facing. Your issues are likely not related to the question, but rather to the remaining of your not-shared code

Comment: Appreciate the help.  There apparently is a problem if both dplyr and plyr libraries have been loaded, so I had to specify dplyr::.  In addition, I changed my "cost" value to an integer because it couldn't convert <double> to <character>.  In any case, it worked!  Thanks again for your help and patience.

```df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(index = row_number(),
    type2 = type) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = type2, values_from = cost, values_fill = 0) %>%
    select(-index)```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using `bind_cols`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = type,
    values_from = cost, 
    values_fill = 0
  ) %>% 
  bind_cols(type = x$type) %>% 
  select(date, type, everything(), -id)
```

```
  date  type   supp  svcs
  <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
1 20-01 supp      5     0
2 20-02 supp     10     0
3 20-03 supp      5     0
4 20-01 svcs      0     2
5 20-02 svcs      0     4
6 20-03 svcs      0     8
```

Comment: Nice one, +1, although I do not know why, but it always hurts when I use external vectors in dplyr...

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problem we do not necessarily need data rectangling. An alternative is to use `purrr::map_dfc` inside `dplyr::mutate` together with `purrr::set_names`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(set_names(unique(type)), 
              ~ ifelse(.x == type, cost, 0))
  )
#>    date type cost supp scvs
#> 1 20-01 supp    5    5    0
#> 2 20-02 supp   10   10    0
#> 3 20-03 supp    5    5    0
#> 4 20-01 scvs    2    0    2
#> 5 20-02 scvs    4    0    4
#> 6 20-03 scvs    8    0    8
```

To simplify this and similar problems I have a package on Github. In this case we could use `over` together with `dist_values`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df %>% 
  mutate(over(dist_values(type), 
              ~ ifelse(.x == type, cost, 0))
  )

#>    date type cost scvs supp
#> 1 20-01 supp    5    0    5
#> 2 20-02 supp   10    0   10
#> 3 20-03 supp    5    0    5
#> 4 20-01 scvs    2    2    0
#> 5 20-02 scvs    4    4    0
#> 6 20-03 scvs    8    8    0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  date = rep(c("20-01", "20-02", "20-03"), 2),
  type = rep(c("supp", "scvs"), each = 3),
  cost = c(5, 10, 5, 2, 4, 8)
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>